# Array of pthread - is thread still active?

Tags: c, pthreads

Server creates threads which deal with clients using

```
if (pthread_create(&array_of_threads[index], NULL, &thread_function, &argument) != 0)
    signal error
```

Threads end on their own once they're done with client.

However, there might be a situation in which server will have to be quit - for example after receiving a signal or a special message.

When that happens I would like to call `pthread_cancel` on the threads that are running (those will call `pthread_cleanup` and free resources, tell clients that the're closing and so on).

Is there a way to do that without additional array of bools telling weather that index in `thread_array` is running?

Comment: Have you tried Signaling :)

Comment: try something like

while(!SIG){ // DO work here }

Comment: Tht;s is some sort of workaround, not an answer to my question.

Comment: Why can't you just call `pthread_cancel` on all threads?

Comment: Well, if I call `pthread_cancel` on `array_of_threads[i]` when there is no active thread will cause problems (like SIGSEGV), won't it?

Comment: Are the threads detached?

Comment: Yes, they are detatched.

Comment: pthread_kill(tid,0) will return an error if the thread exited.  It will not harm the thread otherwise.  But you do need to keep an array of tids.  I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: @MDo, why would it SIGSEGV? `array_of_threads[i]` is not a null pointer, you're not dereferencing any invalid pointers. Trying to `pthread_cancel` on an invalid thread might return an error but shouldn't segfault. There's a non-zero chance that the thread will have exited and the thread ID will have been reused by some other, unrelated thread, but that is true for _anything_ you try to do with the `pthread_t` of a detached thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that without additional array of bools telling weather that index in thread_array is running?

No.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a code skeleton which I used for such a thing. Please anyone who see an issue comment and suggest to improve this answer

```
#include <signal.h>

 int SIG=0;

 // Prototypes
 void SIG_HANDLER(int signum);


int main(void){

     // Register signal and handler
     signal(SIGINT,SIG_HANDLER);

     while(!SIG){
         // DO everything here
         // Such as creating thread for clients
         // Remember you create Detached threads 
     }

    // On SIGNAL clean main function's (main Thread's) resources

    return 0;
}

 // Thread function - Handle individual clients
void* handle_client(void * arg){

    while(!SIG){
      // Handle client here
    }
    return NULL;
}


// Signal handler
 void SIG_HANDLER(int signum){
    int i;
    printf("\nCaught signal : %d \n",signum);
    SIG=1;

    // close all sockets available for clients (end running threads)

    sleep(1);

    exit(signum);
}
```

NOTE - You will need `semaphore` for such and implementation

Guide - http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html

Comment: SIG should have type `sig_atomic_t`. Calling `exit` does not give the child threads a chance to exit gracefully, the `sleep(1)` is an arbitrary grace period that might not be enough. `exit` and `printf` are not [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) functions.